# how to set method put in form_tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, put

how to set method inside form to put in form_tag in rails?, i have form_tag like this :

```
<%= form_tag(url, :method => :put, :multipart => true, :class =>"form-horizontal") do %>
 ......
<% end %>
```

but if i inspect element, form not have method "put" but still "post"?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/stores/1/information/social_update" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 ....
</form>
```

why???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: What's the confusion here, exactly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag):

> If “patch”, “put”, “delete”, or another verb is used, a hidden input with name _method is added to simulate the verb over post.

Therefore, the following code will output the following markup:

```
form_tag('/posts/1', method: :put)
#=> <form action="/posts/1" method="post"> ... <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /> ...
```

This is basically a backwards compatible way of implementing the `PUT` protocol across browsers. Although the form's submission method is `POST`, because of the hidden form input, Rails understands the desired submission method to be `PUT`.

Comment: Did you actually read any of my answer? By default, Rails adds a hidden input specifying that the method should be a `PUT` submission. So while the `form` method attribute is `POST`, Rails processes the submission as if it were `PUT`. This is to accommodate older versions of HTML, which don't support anything but the `GET` and `POST` method.

Answer (score 0):

> The Rails framework encourages RESTful design of your applications, which means you'll be making a lot of "PATCH" and "DELETE" requests (besides "GET" and "POST"). However, most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms.

So, it's perfectly ok to have POST instead of PUT.

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work)

Comment: if i using method "get" in form_tag, the method is change to "get", but if i using method "put"... i still get method post??

Comment: Yes. "Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST with a hidden input named "_method", which is set to reflect the desired method". In this case: "PUT"

Answer (score -4):

Try entering

> ```
> :method => 'get'
> ```

That should do the trick and display get when you inspect the element.